# XeLatex compilation failing when adding specific paragraph-formatting instructions to a document that uses Arabic fonts

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, arabic

I am having difficulty compiling the following latex code using XeLatex. It raises the infamous "Missing \endcsname inserted" error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Arabic Typesetting}
\begin{document}

% Begin paragraph formatting instructions
\parindent0pt
\catcode`\ \active
\def\par{\endgraf\leftskip=0pt\relax}
\obeylines
\def {\ifvmode\advance\leftskip5pt\relax\else\space\fi}
% End paragraph formatting instructions

كلمة.
\end{document}
```

The problem - I guess - is caused by the line:

```
\def {\ifvmode\advance\leftskip5pt\relax\else\space\fi}
```

whose function is to perform paragraph formatting according to my needs (thanks to [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566704/making-the-indentation-of-a-multi-line-paragraph-equal-to-the-indentation-of-the/566713?noredirect=1#comment1428890_566713)). The formatting is not obvious in this small example, but the point is: the part about paragraph formatting needs to be there.

The following are two extracts from the compilation log files when (i) removing the formatting instructions, and (ii) adding the formatting instructions.

First, when removing the formatting instructions, the document compiles fine.

```
Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 13.
% more lines follow in the log file
```

Second, when formatting instructions are added, I get the following at the very end of the log file, after which the compilation fails with the mentioned error.

```
Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring m
```

My question: How would I modify the paragraph formatting to work with Arabic and potentially other RTL non-English languages?

I use Latex under Windows 10 with the following version information: XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX).

Many thanks.

Comment: try to reset the catcode before \end{document}:  ``\catcode`\ =10``

Comment: Thank you :-) This does answer the question i.e. the code can now be compiled. However, when I try it with a larger example where actual paragraph is formatting is required, I do not get the formatting although the code compiles just fine. So do I edit the question with a more interesting content or do I mark this as solved and ask a new question?